# How to Check if a Date is Within a List of Intervals in R?

Tags: r, list, date, tidyr, purrr

I have two data frames (tibbles) with 2 variables each:

- df.POS: ID (ID variable); DATE (Date of positive lab test)
- df.NEG: ID (ID variable); data (Date of negative lab tests (more than 1 test).

Please note that data is a list variable, created with the nest() function of the tidyr package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# negative tests
dates.neg <- ymd(c('2018-02-01', '2018-02-06', '2018-02-10', 
             '2018-02-21', '2018-04-05'))
df.NEG <- tibble(ID = paste0('ID_', rep(1, 5)),
          DATE = dates.neg) %>%
       group_by(ID) %>% 
          nest()
df.NEG

## # A tibble: 1 x 2
##   ID    data            
##   <chr> <list>          
## 1 ID_1  <tibble [5 × 1]>


dates.pos <- ymd(c('2018-02-07', '2018-02-12', '2018-02-13', 
             '2018-02-20', '2018-02-21', '2018-03-18'))

df.POS <- tibble(ID = paste0('ID_', rep(1, 6)),
           DATE = dates.pos)
df.POS

## # A tibble: 6 x 2
##   ID    DATE      
##   <chr> <date>    
## 1 ID_1  2018-02-07
## 2 ID_1  2018-02-12
## 3 ID_1  2018-02-13
## 4 ID_1  2018-02-20
## 5 ID_1  2018-02-21
## 6 ID_1  2018-03-18
```

I would like to find out for which of the positive tests there was also a negative test up to 2 days after the positive test result. I've tried using the map2() function of the purrr package

```
df.TOTAL <- df.POS %>%
  left_join(df.NEG, by = 'ID') %>%
    mutate(TIME = interval(DATE, DATE + days(2)),
           RESULT = map2(data, "DATE", TIME, ~ .x %within% .y))
```

Unfortunaltely, my code doesn't work. The RESULT variable should be logical and return TRUE in case of a negative test result up to 2 days after the positive test. Instead it is a list and returns NULL.

```
df.TOTAL

## # A tibble: 6 x 5
##   ID    DATE       data             TIME                           RESULT
##   <chr> <date>     <list>           <S4: Interval>                 <list>
## 1 ID_1  2018-02-07 <tibble [5 × 1]> 2018-02-07 UTC--2018-02-09 UTC <NULL>
## 2 ID_1  2018-02-12 <tibble [5 × 1]> 2018-02-12 UTC--2018-02-14 UTC <NULL>
## 3 ID_1  2018-02-13 <tibble [5 × 1]> 2018-02-13 UTC--2018-02-15 UTC <NULL>
## 4 ID_1  2018-02-20 <tibble [5 × 1]> 2018-02-20 UTC--2018-02-22 UTC <NULL>
## 5 ID_1  2018-02-21 <tibble [5 × 1]> 2018-02-21 UTC--2018-02-23 UTC <NULL>
## 6 ID_1  2018-03-18 <tibble [5 × 1]> 2018-03-18 UTC--2018-03-20 UTC <NULL>
```

### Can anyone help?

I would appreciate some help. Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that you can test whether any element from a vector of "negative" dates falls within the "positive" interval like so:

```
any(dates.neg %within% interval(dates.pos[1], dates.pos[1] + days(2)))
# [1] FALSE
```

This suggests the following approach using `map2` -- or more usefully, `map2_lgl`:

```
df.TOTAL <- df.POS %>%
  left_join(df.NEG, by = 'ID') %>%
    mutate(TIME = interval(DATE, DATE + days(2)),
           RESULT = map2_lgl(data, TIME, ~any(.x$DATE %within% .y)))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   ID    DATE       data             TIME                           RESULT
#   <chr> <date>     <list>           <S4: Interval>                 <lgl> 
# 1 ID_1  2018-02-07 <tibble [5 x 1]> 2018-02-07 UTC--2018-02-09 UTC FALSE 
# 2 ID_1  2018-02-12 <tibble [5 x 1]> 2018-02-12 UTC--2018-02-14 UTC FALSE 
# 3 ID_1  2018-02-13 <tibble [5 x 1]> 2018-02-13 UTC--2018-02-15 UTC FALSE 
# 4 ID_1  2018-02-20 <tibble [5 x 1]> 2018-02-20 UTC--2018-02-22 UTC TRUE  
# 5 ID_1  2018-02-21 <tibble [5 x 1]> 2018-02-21 UTC--2018-02-23 UTC TRUE  
# 6 ID_1  2018-03-18 <tibble [5 x 1]> 2018-03-18 UTC--2018-03-20 UTC FALSE
```

Thanks to @ubutun for improving the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't be `map2_lgl(data, TIME, ~ any(.x$DATE %within% y))` more self-explanatory? Anyway - great answer, thank you for the valuable information.

Comment: @utubun: Ah, that's right -- way more straightforward.  I'll edit to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's great! :-)

Comment: @NorbertKöhler: Welcome to SO, and happy to help.  If this answer resolved your question, please mark it as accepted.